# how to retrieve data with array id from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving array data from MySQL for form text-fields for edit/update data, each data have same `ID` and `Name` for now, for example text field `name="es_outcall_price"` and I am retrieving 3 times, so what I want it should like..

```
es_outcall_price[]
es_outcall_price[1]
es_outcall_price[2]
```

Each field should their own name as I have written above, now its showing `es_outcall_price` for all 3. I hope all of you will understand my question.

```
<tbody>
    <?
    $query12 = "select * from escorts_rates_outcall where es_id='$es_id'";
    $result12 = @mysql_query ($query12);

    while ($row12 = @mysql_fetch_array ($result12, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
        $es_outcall_time = $row12['es_outcall_time'];
        $es_outcall_price=$row12['es_outcall_price'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select id="es_outcall_time" class="form-control" name="es_outcall_time">
                <option value="$es_outcall_time"><?=$es_outcall_time?></option>
                <option value="null">- Select -</option>
                <option value="Half hour">Half hour</option>
                <option value="1 Hour">1 Hour</option>
                <option value="1.5 Hour">1.5 Hour</option>
                <option value="2 Hours">2 Hours</option>
                <option value="3 Hours">3 Hours</option>
                <option value="4 Hours">4 Hours</option>
                <option value="5 Hours">5 Hours</option>
                <option value="6 Hours">6 Hours</option>
                <option value="7 Hours">7 Hours</option>
                <option value="8 Hours">8 Hours</option>
                <option value="10 Hours">10 Hours</option>
                <option value="12 Hours">12 Hours</option>
                <option value="15 Hours">15 Hours</option>
                <option value="18 Hours">18 Hours</option>
                <option value="24 Hours">24 Hours</option>
                <option value="36 Hours">36 Hours</option>
                <option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="es_outcall_price" name="es_outcall_price" placeholder="$ (AUD)" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$es_outcall_price?>">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" title="" class="add-remove"><span class="fa fa-times-circle-o field-required"/></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
</tbody>

I am using this JS when i am inserting code after clicking "add more row"

//Code for "Add More" OUTCALL text fields button 

var counterOutcall = 1;
jQuery('a.add-outcall').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
counterOutcall++;

var wrapper = jQuery("table.table-bordered.responsive-table.outcall"); //Fields wrapper 

var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td>' + counterOutcall + '</td><td><select id="es_outcall_time[]' + counterOutcall + '" class="form-control" name="es_outcall_time[]' + counterOutcall + '"><option value="null">- Select -</option><option value="Half hour">Half hour</option><option value="1 Hour">1 Hour</option><option value="1.5 Hour">1.5 Hour</option><option value="2 Hours">2 Hours</option><option value="3 Hours">3 Hours</option><option value="4 Hours">4 Hours</option><option value="5 Hours">5 Hours</option><option value="6 Hours">6 Hours</option><option value="7 Hours">7 Hours</option><option value="8 Hours">8 Hours</option><option value="10 Hours">10 Hours</option><option value="12 Hours">12 Hours</option><option value="15 Hours">15 Hours</option><option value="18 Hours">18 Hours</option><option value="24 Hours">24 Hours</option><option value="36 Hours">36 Hours</option><option value="48 Hours">48 Hours</option></select' + counterOutcall + '"/></td><td><input name="es_outcall_price[]" id="es_outcalll_price[]' + counterOutcall + '" placeholder="$ (AUD)" class="form-control" type="text"/></td><td><a href="#' + counterOutcall + '" title="" class="add-remove"><span class="fa fa-times-circle-o field-required"/></span></a></td></tr>');

jQuery(wrapper).append(newRow);


jQuery(wrapper).on('click', '.add-remove', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$(this).closest('tr').remove();

})
});
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poKmT.png)

[after retrieving data from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zYeA.png)

Comment: I don't understand can you show the PHP code you are using?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I want like  "es_incall_time[]"  "es_incall_time[]2" es_incall_time[]3 ...it can be any numbers of!

Comment: If you want i can send link and login id/pass for exact look!

Comment: I think you are just trying to make your form have the same input names maybe? If so, just array the name of the form field `name="es_outcall_time[]"`. If not the case, you need to explain more.

Comment: Sorry, I think I edited your post at the exact same time you did and overwrote what you put in...

Comment: show the schema of your database with example values

Comment: Added database structure, Added image for edit the existing data

Comment: I am pretty sure all you are wanting to do is just array your name: `<select class="form-control" name="es_outcall_time[]">`. When you submit, you will get an array `Array([es_outcall_time]=>Array([0]=>Whatever1,[1]=>Whatever2,[2]=>Whatever3))`

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, Its working now, Thanks for help!